# Redirect ruby exec output

Tags: ruby, exec

I am executing a SVN command using ruby's exec. I DON'T want the
output to appear on the console. I want it to go to a ruby string variable
on which I will do some processing.

ruby code - `exec "svn log repo"`

This code shows me the result of the execution of the svn command. I don't want it in console.

Please help me.

Comment: why the -1 for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec` will not work since the new process will replace the current one (your script will end at `exec`; following statements will never be executed).

Use backticks:

```
string_variable = `svn log repo`
```